# rJava package installation error

Tags: r, installation

I am facing below compilation error while installing rJava package
I have below R version, and java version. Please can any one knows how to fix the below compilation error and install rJava package in linux

```
[root@localhost ~]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
[root@localhost ~]# R --version
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Error logs:

```
Warning: R include directory is empty -- perhaps need to install R-devel.rpm or similar
gcc -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/java/latest/include -I/usr/java/latest/include/linux -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Rglue.c -o Rglue.o
In file included from Rglue.c:2:0:
rJava.h:23:15: fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:132: recipe for target 'Rglue.o' failed
make: *** [Rglue.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpMX8OgU/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("rJava") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```